# ZF2 - dynamically inject view manager templates

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have multiple modules in a ZF2 application. I would like to have different 'not_found_template' and 'exception_template' view_manager settings for each module.

How can I write the piece of code that dynamically injects the settings for these templates? I really need this code to work, even if caching is enabled.

Thanks,

Comment: > for each module

The point is, there is no such thing as that it's a "Module's" controller. If you take ZfcUser and its controller. When you override the login action with your own `MyUser\Controller\LoginController`, which "module" is this? It was defined for ZfcUser, but you override it as MyUser. What is the expected behaviour? Module's are in ZF2 terms just containers with some code, they can override each other very easily.

Answer (score 0):

in your `module.php` link to the MVC Event `EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR` this event is called when the route/controller etc. was not found and place there your logic what response zf2 should return.

```
$eventManager->getSharedManager()->attach('*', MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR, function(MvcEvent $e){
    // place your logic here
}, -100);
```

don't know if there is a other possibility but zend merge all your configs into one big array so multiple `not_found_template` in your config can not work because they get merged by key.